# How to fit a square into a rectangle?

Tags: html, css

I try to fit a square into a rectangle. I used `max-width`, `max-height` and `aspect-ratio`, but it works only in portrait mode and fails in landscape mode. This shows how Firefox renders it:

[image: works] [image: fails]

This is the example.

```js
function portrait() {
  document.body.style.width = "10em";
  document.body.style.height = "14em";
}

function landscape() {
  document.body.style.width = "14em";
  document.body.style.height = "10em";
}

document.getElementById("button0").addEventListener('click', portrait);
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', landscape);

portrait();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#page {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1ex solid blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto min-content;
}
.square {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
canvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1ex solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.buttons {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1ex solid green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="square">
    <canvas width="100" height="100">
    </canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <input id="button0" type="button" value="Works"/>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Fails"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to fit the red and green boxes into the blue box?

Comment: try to remove height:100% to div with id page

Comment: This is a tough one. It looks like aspect-ratio is overriding the max-height as in it appears to be using the width to calculate the height. I found some discussion on [github](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5721) but I'm still not clear if there's a definitive answer in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-4/#ratios).  Hopefully someone can clarify this.

Comment: Can't you use js to resize the canvas or the #square div?

Comment: Could you describe more what you mean by fitting a square into a rectangle? Add an image if you possible.

Comment: A resize observer in js would be the hardcore approach imho. I think the OP wants the red square and green box to fit in the blue div. The square has to remain square and fill up as much space as possible in the blue div and work with the blue div in both portrait and landscape aspect ratios.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it to work using `container-type`. There are nifty container unit called cqmin and cqmax. cqmin is the minimum of the inline and block container size which is handy when the aspect ratio changes. By declaring the square as a container and using the `size` value rather than `inline-size` and setting the width of the canvas to be 100cqmin it fills the height or the width of the grid item, depending on what is the smaller container size (because the `size` value looks at both the block and inline lengths)  Thankfully container queries seem to be nearly universally supported.

```js
function portrait() {
  //I changed these from em to px so I could make sure the body and #page div sizes were as specified.
  document.body.style.width = "250px";
  document.body.style.height = "300px";
}

function landscape() {
  document.body.style.width = "300px";
  document.body.style.height = "250px";
}

document.getElementById("button0").addEventListener('click', portrait);
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', landscape);

portrait();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#page {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1ex solid blue;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

.square {
  container-type: size; /* make it size and not inline-size so the units work for both inline and block dimensions */
}

canvas {
  border: 1ex solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 100cqmin; /* this is the secret sauce */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.buttons {
  border: 1ex solid green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="square">
   <canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <input id="button0" type="button" value="Works"/>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="Works!!!!"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work Firefox 102.7esr (Debian 11 default). https://caniuse.com/css-container-query-units

Answer (score 0):

Try using orientation and `@container` rule!
[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container)

**Note: If you want to do it by real page size change the `@container` to `@media`**

```js
function portrait() {
  document.body.style.width = "10em";
  document.body.style.height = "14em";
}

function landscape() {
  document.body.style.width = "14em";
  document.body.style.height = "10em";
}

document.getElementById("button0").addEventListener('click', portrait);
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener('click', landscape);

portrait();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#page {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1ex solid blue;
  display: block;
  container-type: size;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
}
.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
@container (orientation: landscape) {
.square {
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto;
  }
}

@container (orientation: portrait) {
.square {
   width: 100%;
  }
}
canvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1ex solid red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.buttons {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1ex solid green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="square">
      <canvas>
      </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <input id="button0" type="button" value="Works"/>
      <input id="button1" type="button" value="Fails"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying the same thing but I couldn't stop the bottom element with the buttons in overflowing the parent.

Comment: You didn't tell you want this. Add you request to question I will answer you within an hour.

Comment: Hi @Alijvhr, I wasn't the originator of the question, just saying I spent a lot of time with `@container (aspect-ratio > 1/1)` and got nowhere. If you find a way to keep the children in the container I'm all ears.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, Checked your answer and I think it's a better way than mine actually. But updated my answer to keep children inside.

Comment: Thanks @Alijvhr. This is a real head-scratcher for sure. Have a great evening. Best wishes.